# Android: Multiple declaration error due to multiple header file in cpp

Tags: android, c++, android-6.0-marshmallow, cyanogenmod

While compiling android source code, I get multiple declaration error as the

> same variable is declared in 2 different enum of 2 different header
>   file

? what should I do now and some variables are different in both header so I can't remove them also.

Comment: wrap them in different namespaces.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: If i use different namespace means I should be retyping the code right? is there any other way?

Comment: if different header contains variables of same name, i can't think another way other than namespace as a solution.  
and yes you have to retype the code.

Comment: Actually there are 2 different enum in 2 header files, it is showing error for variable declared inside that enum. Both enum are different right. So why is it showing error like this!

Comment: @VigneshPrasadV No, enums don't have their namespace and their element stick outside. This can be avoided by using `enum class` which is strongly typed enums with namespace. But this was introduced only in C++11. Good practice for regular enums is to use prefix in each enum member unique for the enum like `enum PixelType {EPT_Grayscale, EPT_RGB}` where E stands for enum, and PT for PixelType